# R strptime issue when using %b to format a date

Tags: r, date-format, strptime

Before marking as duplicate, I've tried a few other solutions, namely these:

[R, strptime(), %b, trying to convert character to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785587/r-strptime-b-trying-to-convert-character-to-date-format)

[strptime, as.POSIXct and as.Date return unexpected NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726894/strptime-as-posixct-and-as-date-return-unexpected-na)

But neither seem to work for me.

---

I'm trying to convert a time format `Dec-18` to a POSIXct time (would be `2018-12-01` in this case). I'm attempting to use `strptime` with `%b` and `%y` to achieve this as so:

```
> strptime("Dec-18", format = "%b-%y")
[1] NA
```

But obviously it is not working. I'm reading a out about "locales" and such, but the above solutions did not work for me. I attempted the following:

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
[1] "C"
> strptime("Dec-18", format = "%b-%y")
[1] NA
```

It was also suggested to use this locale, `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_GB.UTF-8")`, but I get an error when trying to use this:

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_GB.UTF-8")
[1] ""
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_GB.UTF-8") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "en_GB.UTF-8" cannot be honored
```

Kind of at a loss for what to do here. My abbreviated months seem right based off this:

```
> month.abb
 [1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"
```

Here's the version of R that I am running:

```
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11) -- "Great Truth"
Copyright (C) 2019 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The month and year does not form a date. Adding a "01" in front of it will R detect it as a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution will be this:

```r
as.Date(x = paste0("01-", "Dec-18"),
        format = "%d-%b-%y")
#> [1] "2018-12-01"

format(x = as.Date(x = paste0("01-", "Dec-18"),
                   format = "%d-%b-%y"),
       format = "%b-%y")
#> [1] "Dec-18"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

`R` doesn't recognise Dec-18 as date. Add a `01-` so that it can detect it as date, and then display as you prefer.

Comment: Dang, should have tried this. Slight quirk to date formatting I guess, but nice work around.

Answer (score 3):

The most simplest solution would be

```
library(zoo)
as.Date(as.yearmon("Dec-18", "%b-%y"))
#[1] "2018-12-01"
```

---

The issue in the OP's code is that `strptime` or `as.Date` requires a day too.  If it is not there, the format is not complete for a Date.  One option would be to `paste` a day in `strptime` and it works

```
strptime(paste0("Dec-18", "-01"), format = "%b-%y-%d")
#[1] "2018-12-01 EST"
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Curious to see if anyone knows why base R `strptime` isn't working, but this works in the meantime.

Comment: @giraffehere  dates include day also

Answer (score 3):

With `lubridate`, you can do:

```
parse_date_time("Dec-18", "my")

[1] "2018-12-01 UTC"
```

Comment: thanks! this is what I was looking for.